# Unity - OnTriggerStay2D() for 2 colliders simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm using an `OnTriggerStay2D()` function that does something while an object in inside the collider (doesn't matter what). However, sometimes I have another, so a total of 2 colliders that may stay inside that collider. The two colliders are not on the same `Game Object`. 
I'm trying like this:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obj1"))
    {
        //do something
    } 
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obj2"))
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

but *do something else* just never happens when `Obj1` is already inside. How to make a collider sense two colliders at once for `OnTriggerStay2D()`?

**EDIT TO CLARIFY:**

The `OnTriggerStay2D()` still gets called. The issue is that the code never gets to the `if` statement where I have to *do something else* comment.

Comment: You are saying that `OnTriggerStay2D` is never called again if there is an Object already colliding? If this is false, please edit your question and explain it more.

Comment: Nope, I said precisely that _do something else_ doesn't happen. That only means that the code never "gets into" that `if` statement.

Comment: @Programmer edited, sorry to make it confusing.

Comment: That's fine. You shouldn't expect OnTriggerStay2D to be called in the-same frame. `Collider2D other` cannot contain multiple trigger information. After *Obj1* is returned, OnTriggerStay2D will be called in the next frame or so with *Obj2* returned. Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: This explains a lot, but for my collider `Obj2` is like it doesn't even exist. How to get around this? I made double sure that I didn't misspell the tags, the gameobjects do have the tags set up and so on
**and** that I have the tags on the same gameobject that has the collider.

Comment: You put `Debug.Log` in the second if statement and that doesn't get called at-all? If this is true, please remove non useful stuff from the project, close Unity, zip the project, upload to somewhere and provide link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I did try the `Debug.Log` thing but I wasn't wrote at all. 
The colliders are all the same. 
But first I just try turning off and on Unity :)

Comment: Yep, a simple restart solved it. No clue what I did wrong, but thanks for your help. You may convert your second comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `OnTriggerStay2D` function is called, it does not report multiple GameObjects that is touching. It returns one trigger/Collider2D  information only. After the next physics frame or so, it will be called again. This time it will return the other trigger/Collider2D  information that is touching the-same GameObject.

In your case, after *Obj1* is returned, `OnTriggerStay2D` will be called in the next physics frame or so with *Obj2* returned.